# Exercises 2.3.7 and 2.3.10 from Huybrecht's book on complex geometry

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

I'm trying to do some exercises in Huybrecht's book:

Let $x\in \mathbb{P}^n$ and consider the linear system of $s \in H^0(\mathbb{P}^n,\mathcal{O}(1))$ such that  $s(x)=0.$ Show that it defines a holomorphic map $\varphi : \mathbb{P}^n \setminus \{x\} \to \mathbb{P}^{n-1}$. Describe this map geometrically.

Let $n=2$ and $C=\varphi(\mathbb{P}^1)$ where $\varphi$ is Veronese map defined by $\varphi([x,y])=[x^2:xy:y^2]$. Study the induced map $ C \setminus \{x\} \to \mathbb{P}^{1}$. (There are two cases to be considered: $x \in C$ and $x \notin C$)

I don't see how to do the second question.

For the first one: We identify $H^0(\mathbb{P}^n,\mathcal{O}(1))$ with $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$ naturally. If  I suppose $x=[1:0:\dots:0]$, then the linear system becomes just the subspace defined by the equation $x_0 =0 $. And the holomorphic map $\varphi$ is $[x_0:\dots:x_n] \in \mathbb{P}^{n} \setminus \{x\} \mapsto [x_1:\dots:x_n]$.

I don't know if my construction is good, or even if this is what he looking for. As for what's meant by "describe geometrically" in this case, I'm not sure how to proceed for every $x$.

Any help with these two questions? Many thanks.

Comment: Please update your title with the chapter/exercise number, so it is easier for people to find.

Comment: I update my title, thanks.

Comment: The geometric interpretation in (1) is that of projection from a point.

Comment: I know it should be a projection, but what kind of projection?

Comment: What do you mean by ‘what kind of projection’? Given a point x and a hyperplane not containing x, you can always project x, which is to say that for any other point p, draw the line xp and look at where it intersects the hyperplane.